# Assigning a value to the Controller depending on a link being click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a website with two forms one for inHole and the other Surface. The forms are identical but I would like to know where did the user clicked so I can assign a value to my SureyLocationID in the controller so I can refer to it later in my database if I need to without creating 2 views. Is there a way of doing so?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code? Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Olivier tbh, i havent tried nothing yet because i don't know how to go about it, i would just like to know if a link can assign a value to my controller really

Comment: What are the user's options to click? Url link? Buttons?

Comment: @Olivier a Url link but they share the same url link, is there a way to identify from whish url link the client got access to the page so i can assign a value in my controller?

Comment: When you say forms are identical it means same kind of forms at 2 pages/urls? or this is one single form with 2 click events?

Comment: Will the two forms be on the same view? If yes, why do you need two identical forms on the same view? Why not use just one and add a hidden field to differentiate the inHole/Surface case? You can set up the value of this field with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to pass a parameter with your link like :

```
http://example.com/over/there?sureyLocationID=inHole
```

or

```
http://example.com/over/there?sureyLocationID=Surface
```

So you just have to check the URL and retrieve the information you pass through it

Answer (score 1):

In your MVC view have a button or anchor tag like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("YOUR_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME", new { comingFromInHole = true }  )'>NAME_FOR_THIS_ELEMENT</a>
```

or

```
<input type="button" 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("YOUR_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME", new { comingFromInHole = true} )'" 
       value="NAME_FOR_THIS_ELEMENT"/>
```

And in you MVC Controller:

```
public IActionResult YOUR_ACTION_NAME(bool comingFromInHole)
{
      if (comingFromInHole)
      {
          // logic related coming from hole 
      }
      else
      {
          // Logic related to surface
      } 
}
```

If you don't want to use boolean true or false, then you could use enumeration (or your custom defined type..etc) and use that as well:

```
public enum Types {InHole, Surface };
```

Then controller action signature will be changed to take in Types enum

```
public IActionResult YOUR_ACTION_NAME(Types type)
```

and modify your button or anchor link to send enum type to controller as below:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("YOUR_ACTION_NAME", "YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME", new { Types=HomeController.Types.InHole}   )'>NAME_FOR_THIS_ELEMENT</a>
```